# Alert manager Email Configuration

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager

Monitoring all hosts and Vm's and with Prometheus and grafana.
I configured email notifications to our DevOps team and now I want to send the same alert to DevOps team and owner of the VM at the same time to make sure owner(employee ) also know the warnings(many Vm's and diff users) , I need some suggestions How can I Achieve that!!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you already have email sending configured so for multiple email receivers it should look something like this:

```
receivers:
- name: 'team-X-mails'
  email_configs:
  - to: 'team1@example.org, team2@example.org'
```

PS.
different receiver groups for different alert rules:

```
  routes:
  - match:
      alertname: team1VM_down
    receiver: team1
  - match:
      alertname: team2VM_down
    receiver: team2
```

Comment: Thanks allot for your time and answer . Let me give an example to make it more clear . Team - ABC ,( VM1 - Email1 @outlook.com) , ( VM2- Email2@outlook.com) , (VM3-Email3#outlook.com) . Here, we have three VM's and each VM got different email address . When there is an alert in VM2, it send notifications to team abc email and I want to send a notification to that particular VM2 email which is email2@outlook.com. In the above config which you sent , we can send the same alert to other both the emails , but one email is common for teams and vm email is different for all machines!!!!!

Comment: Aah that makes sense now. I don't know of a way to send alerts to different receiver groups depending on metrics label. The way I've done it is to make different alerts for different receiver groups. Edited my answer.